# PHP Webservice Connected but unauthorized error when call a function

Tags: php, web-services, soap

I calling a web service, it connecting successfully and also returns its methods, 
but when i calling to one of this function it gets error unauthorized..

**my code is here**

```
try { 
$service = new SoapClient("http://www.go-to-orbit.com/oos/solo/soapServer.php?wsdl");

$header = new SoapHeader('http://oncore.qubitwebtechnologies.com/', 'AuthorisationHeader', array('login' => "ONCORE",'password' => "ONCORE"), false);
$service->__setSoapHeaders(array($header));   

var_dump($service->__getFunctions());

$response = $service->__soapCall("getAllOnHand", array() );
}
catch (Exception $e)
{
    echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}

print_r($response);
```

**result is**

```
    array(2) { [0]=> string(18) "Map getAllOnHand()" [1]=> string(33) "int getOnHand(string $partNumber)" } Caught exception: Unauthorized
```

i tried this for 2 days but no luck, can anyone one save me please

error message

```
Exception object(SoapFault)#4 (9) { ["message":protected]=> string(12) "Unauthorized" ["string":"Exception":private]=> string(0) "" ["code":protected]=> int(0) ["file":protected]=> string(47) "/home/qubitweb/public_html/oncore/jumi/soap.php" ["line":protected]=> int(87) ["trace":"Exception":private]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(6) { ["file"]=> string(47) "/home/qubitweb/public_html/oncore/jumi/soap.php" ["line"]=> int(87) ["function"]=> string(10) "__soapCall" ["class"]=> string(10) "SoapClient" ["type"]=> string(2) "->" ["args"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(12) "getAllOnHand" [1]=> array(0) { } } } } ["previous":"Exception":private]=> NULL ["faultstring"]=> string(12) "Unauthorized" ["faultcode"]=> string(6) "Sender" }
```

Comment: How do you know that you need to pass User Name and Password in Header , When I load same WSDL, I couldn't find any AuthorisationHeader node in request.

Comment: i got this instruction from service provider
 
url of webservice
http://www.go-to-orbit.com/oos/solo/soapServer.php

    send a soap header called "AuthHeader" that contains a username and password field.  The user name is ONCORE and password ONCORE.
    use the uri "http://www.go-to-orbit.com/"

any idea with works on that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class SOAPStruct
{
    function __construct($user, $pass) 
    {
        $this->username = $user;
        $this->password = $pass;
    }
}

$service = new SoapClient("http://www.go-to-orbit.com/oos/solo/soapServer.php?wsdl");

$auth = new SOAPStruct("ONCORE","ONCORE");

$header = new     SoapHeader("http://oncore.qubitwebtechnologies.com/","AuthHeader",$auth,false); 

$service->__setSoapHeaders($header);   

$response = $service->getAllOnHand();


var_dump( $response );
```

This Code will working now, You need to set values to same keys which are given like AuthHeader, username, password.

Comment: cheers mate, It's working with your codes. thank you very much, cheers...!